# Console application progress bar is slow

Tags: c#, progress-bar, console-application

I have a method that downloads a file over a TCP connection, and I want to display a download completion meter on the console.
The method I'm currently using is raising events to display the progress bar and update it.

My problem is the display is not async and it is slowing down the download process quite a lot. I tried processing events with Tasks, but I couldn't produce a good result, as multiple threads would update the progress bar simultaneously and it would be a mess.

The Download method :

```
public void DownloadFile(Stream stream)
{
    if (!stream.CanWrite)
    {
        // The stream can't be written : invalid argument
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // Get the data lenght first
    var dataLength = long.Parse(ReadLine());

    // Send ready flag
    WriteLine("{OK}");

    var buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    long bytesWritten = 0;
    try
    {
        // Notify that the stream transfert started if the handler has been implemented
        StreamTransfertStartEvent?.Invoke(dataLength);

        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesWritten += bytesRead;

            // Notify that the stream transfert progress changed if the handler has been implemented
            StreamTransfertProgressEvent?.Invoke(bytesWritten);

            // The file has been totally written
            if (bytesWritten == dataLength)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        StreamTransfertFailEvent?.Invoke();
        throw new NetworkException();
    }
}
```

You can see in the code above the 3 events I'm using to update the progress bar :

- StreamTransfertStartEvent
- StreamTransfertProgressEvent
- StreamTransfertFailEvent

And for the progress bar update code (only the code called by the StreamTransfertProgressEvent handler):

```
public static void Update(long current)
{
    var newCompletion = (int)((decimal)current / total * 100);

    // Transfert progressed
    if (completion != newCompletion)
    {
        completion = newCompletion;

        if (completion % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, lastLine - 1);
            Console.Write(new string('=', completion / 2 - 1));
            Console.Write('>');
        }

        var leftStart = 52 - total.ToString().Length - 7 - current.ToString().Length;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(leftStart, lastLine);
        Console.Write(current);

        // Transfert finished
        if (completion == 100)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(50, lastLine - 1);
            Console.Write('=');

            End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the downloading async so the main thread is free to interact with user i.e. update progressbar

Comment: Alright, but how would you update the progress bar from the main thread ? With events ?

Comment: You could always update the progress bar on other threads and synchronize that code with a lock?

Comment: I tried doing this, but couldn't get it right, the amount of time necessary to update the progress bar was still the same, when  the download was finished, the progress bar would still update. I was thinking, maybe I could have a stack to store the values to update the progress bar, and each time a new value is put in the stack, the older ones that weren't displayed would be deleted and only the latest would be displayed. Combined with a lock. Do you think this could work ?